# Output results from Oracle Ref cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can i rewrite below pl/sql block in order to avoid hard code column names one by one ? Below data are from OE schema. For orders table there are 8 columns on this table. Is it possible to output the results without hard code column names ? Any help is appreciated.

```
create or replace PACKAGE show_details AS
TYPE rt_order IS REF CURSOR RETURN orders%ROWTYPE;
TYPE typ_cust_rec IS RECORD
(cust_id NUMBER(6), cust_name VARCHAR2(20),
custphone customers.phone_numbers%TYPE,
credit NUMBER(9,2), cust_email VARCHAR2(30));
TYPE rt_cust IS REF CURSOR RETURN typ_cust_rec;
--Get order detail
PROCEDURE get_order(p_orderid IN NUMBER, p_cv_order IN OUT rt_order);
--Get customer detail
PROCEDURE get_cust(p_custid IN NUMBER, p_cv_cust IN OUT rt_cust);
END show_details;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY show_details 
AS 
PROCEDURE get_order (p_orderid IN NUMBER, p_cv_order IN OUT rt_order)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN p_cv_order FOR
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE order_id = p_orderid;
-- CLOSE p_cv_order
END get_order;
PROCEDURE get_cust (p_custid IN NUMBER, p_cv_cust IN OUT rt_cust)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN p_cv_cust FOR
SELECT customer_id, cust_first_name,phone_numbers,
credit_limit,cust_email FROM customers WHERE customer_id = p_custid;
-- CLOSE p_cv_cust
END get_cust;
END;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED;
declare
cur_orders show_details.rt_order;
v_ordertab cur_orders%ROWTYPE;
begin
show_details.get_order(p_orderid =>2397, p_cv_order =>cur_orders);
LOOP
FETCH cur_orders INTO v_ordertab;
EXIT WHEN cur_orders%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ORDER_ID: ' || v_ordertab.ORDER_ID || ' ORDER_DATE: ' ||        v_ordertab.ORDER_DATE || ' ORDER_MODE: ' || v_ordertab.ORDER_MODE || ' CUSTOMER_ID: ' || v_ordertab.CUSTOMER_ID);
END LOOP;
exception
when others then
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Error Code : ' || SQLCODE);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're executing this from SQL Developer, you can use the [variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm) and [print](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm) commands, which are carried over from SQL*Plus:

```
variable cur_orders refcursor;
exec show_details.get_order(p_orderid => 2397, p_cv_order => :cur_orders);
print cur_orders

CUR_ORDERS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORDER_ID                                CUSTOMER_ID                             ORDER_MODE                              ORDER_DATE                
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------------- 
2397                                    42                                      0                                       03-JAN-15
```

Notice that you're passing the ref cursor variable as a bind variable, so there is a colon before the name in the call (`:cur_order`). And you need to `run script` rather than `run statement`.

`exec` is just a shorthand for an anonymous block, so you could do it explicitly if you prefer, but the effect is the same:

```
var cur_orders refcursor;
begin
  show_details.get_order(p_orderid => 2397, p_cv_order => :cur_orders);
end;
/
print cur_orders
```

You can also get the output in the result grid if you prefer, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27006514/266304), but `print` is a bit closer to your `dbms_output` version. Or you can have a wrapper function so you could call query the procedure from a plain SQL call; depends what your end goal is, and if you're just manually executing the procedure to check the output then `print` may also be good enough.